# Calling a Windows batch file from a GNUMakeFile

Tags: cygwin, gnu-make

I have a GNUMakeFile (with that name) in a folder, also with a batch file `run.bat` which writes to standard output.

How can I call that batch file from the GNUMakeFile?

I've tried `@CALL run.bat` but the CALL command doesn't seem to be supported.

`cmd run.bat` just puts the cwgwin terminal into a sort of "hybrid DOS state".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cmd /C run.bat` will do it.

For more help on `cmd`, type `cmd /?` in the cygwin terminal.